# Pass optional parameters to URL

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I want to pass **optional params** such as **filters & page numbers** to route. I'm using **RequestOptions** to pass query parameters and it works for filter and paginataion, but URL never changes.

*e.g: i have `uri/cars` route, when i click second page content is updating for 2nd page but URL still same as `uri/cars`.*

I want `uri/cars?page=2` when i do this example. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `router.navigate()`, you can use the `queryParams` object to send additional parameters.

In your example, you could use something like this:

`this.router.navigate(['uri/cars'], {queryParams: {'page': 2}});`

Comment: does this provide me to change page on url ? if a write to browser url bar uri/cars?page=30, will 30st page load?

Comment: If that's how it's implemented in your application